# Receive data from an $.ajax call with laravel controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-4

I am trying to take selected option from `<select>`, pass it through to method `show()` in controller, use it to retrieve data from database, and then return it as json to the success method in `$.ajax`. All this is happening through `jquery.ajax`.

## My Problem

How can i get/receive data i pass from `$.ajax` request to manipulate the database?

Here is the code I am using:

#### routes.php

```
Route::post('rate/units',array('as'=>'unitRoute','uses'=>'RateController@show'));
```

#### RateController.php

```
public function show()
{
    $row[] = $_POST['deg'];

    return json_encode($row);
}
```

#### Views

```
<select class="form-control choosedegree" name="sem" id="semester">
    <option value="" selected="selected" disabled>Select Semester</option>
    <option value="1">Year 1, Semester 1</option>
    <option value="2">Year 1, Semester 2</option>
    <option value="3">Year 2, Semester 1</option>
    <option value="4">Year 2, Semester 2</option>
    <option value="5">Year 3, Semester 1</option>
    <option value="6">Year 3, Semester 2</option>
    <option value="7">Year 4, Semester 1</option>
    <option value="8">Year 4, Semester 2</option>
</select>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select#semester').on('change', function() {
        var optionSelected = $(this).find("option:selected");
        semesterSelected  = optionSelected.val();
        console.log(semesterSelected);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            url : "rate/units",
            data: { sem : semesterSelected },
            success: function(data) {
                var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                var i = 0;
                console.log(data.iyo);

                $.each(obj, function() {
                    console.log(this[0]);
                    console.log(this[1]);
                    console.log(this[2]);
                    console.log(this[3]);
                    console.log(this[4]);

                    i++;
                });
            }
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            alert('done');
        })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert('No response from server');
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: use `return Response::json($row));` instead of `json_encode`. I haven't confirmed it, but I suspect it'll set the proper headers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You post data can be retrieved using Input:

```
public function show()
{
    $semester = Input::get('sem');

    return json_encode($semester);
}
```

To debug it you can:

```
public function show()
{
    Log::info(Input::all());

    $semester = Input::get('sem');

    return json_encode($semester);
}
```

And then execute at the console

```
php artisan tail
```

Comment: Input is not available in `laravel 5.1`.

Comment: how would you print data on view side?

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Laravel version  5.4.36 and I used this method to retrieve data from ajax request.

Controller:

```
public function processData(Request $request){

   $data = $request->all();
   print_r($data);
   echo $data['email'];

}
```

View:

```
function someMethod(prm){

    $.get("{!! route('routename') !!}",{email:prm},function(res){
        console.log('Response:',res);
    });

}
```